# WooCommerce : Direct Checkout Page

Tags: plugins

I would like to redirect to the checkout page directly upon clicking the "add to cart" button.
Or a Direct Buy Now Feature.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: a free wordpress plugin to achieve that : http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/

Answer (score 3):

My friend Ewout just answered this question a couple months ago on stackoverflow. Add the following to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
    return $checkout_url;
}
```

Here's a link to his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15597933/1543310

Comment: add_to_cart_redirect filter is deprecated since WooCommerce version 3. Use woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect filter instead.
Moreover, get_checkout_url() is also deprecated... you use the wc_get_checkout_url() function instead so the function code should be :
function redirect_to_checkout() {
 return wc_get_checkout_url();
}